# Can you convert a stackable dryer 220 to a 110, and how?

Tags: dryer

Can you convert a stackable dryer 220v to 110v? I don't have 4 prong outlet. Need to be 3 prong regular plug for regular outlet.

Comment: Too bad you can't trade circuits with Rupert https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/150144/how-can-i-convert-a-220v-lighting-circuit-to-110v who wants to switch a 220 circuit (which you need) to 110 (which you have)!

Comment: Does your house have the remaining utilities needed for a dryer (in particular, a vent connection to the outdoors)?  Or are you trying to use an electric dryer in a house set up exclusively for gas dryers?

Answer (score 3):

No. A 220 V to 240 V clothes dryer cannot be modified to operate on 120 V only.

There are very small clothes dryers that operate on 110 V, but they are so small that it is clear that a standard 240 V clothes dryer requires much more power than could be supplied by a 120 V 20 A circuit. [Magic Chef 2.6 Cu Ft clothes dryer](https://www.walmart.com/ip/Magic-Chef-2-6-Cu-Ft-Compact-Electric-Dryer-in-White/29559158?wmlspartner=wlpa&selectedSellerId=0&adid=22222222227023238657&wl0=&wl1=g&wl2=c&wl3=40343668832&wl4=aud-481962823846:pla-78307298072&wl5=9026945&wl6=&wl7=&wl8=&wl9=pla&wl10=8175035&wl11=online&wl12=29559158&wl13=&veh=sem&gclid=CjwKCAiAt4rfBRBKEiwAC678KRi4dnkNcg2794Yxd-s9A1_d_IbkRtLdA3hqrOhIA1LNdQqK7j9FrRoCgKcQAvD_BwE)

Answer (score 1):

It can be done, but it is wizard tier work.  You are relying on the fact that most of the interior equipment runs on 120V and only the heater needs 240V.  You also feed the heating element on 110V, which that it runs at half the amperage (around 10A) making it output 1/4 the heat.  **This makes it dry clothes verrrrry slowly**.  *This will be hard on the clothing; tumbling is what turns clothing into lint and makes them threadbare*.

The simple fact is that those familiar AC outlets are not magic, and simply cannot provide unlimited amounts of power.  Appliances that plug into 120V outlets are very limited in how much heat they can make. That is why powerful heaters use 240V.

You are better off selling the unit on Craigslist and buying a gas unit on Craigslist.

Edit: If cost is no object, there are now "heat pump" dryers which *do not* use heat.  After all, we don't care about heating clothes, we care about drying them. They replace the heating element with a dehumidifier.  Forehead-slap simple if you think about it LOL.  As such, they use far less electricity, and a 120V <12A dryer is now *technically possible*.  Note that heat pump dryers need a water outlet, but they can just use the one for the washer.

Comment: Your answer - and ThreePhaseEel's comment - suggest gas. The OP has made no indication that I can see that gas is even an option.

Comment: @manassehkatz there's always propane.